# How we can load dll dynamically in windows 8.1 store apps?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

Right now I'm learning about Windows 8.1 Store Apps and  Created Portable class library which supports win 8.1 having user controls.I just want to load the dll of that library dynamically in the 
main app using reflection,but I'm struck in middle as Assembly.loadfile() not supported in WINRT store apps.can you please provide any alternative solution for loading dll into store apps?

Comment: No, you can't get that when you target WinRT.  No alternative either.  Lots of reasons, but primary one is that DLL Hell is aggressively eliminated in WinRT.  An app package must include *all* executables and runs isolated, it cannot use any from another package.  To ensure it *always* runs on the user's device.  So it doesn't make any sense to use LoadFile().

Comment: In C++ you can achieve dynamic loading of a DLL (one in the app package), and activate runtime classes within. I guess PCLs are a different scenario altogether, being CLR assemblies.